# Not able to download the helm through dockerfile- 403 forbidden

Tags: dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

I have Gitlab runner Dockerfile and i am testing helm lint on the runner itself and my stages will give me an output of it and i used to correct helm linting issues. now Dockerbuild is not able to fetch the repo.

```
Now on my new build the command fails on my Dockerfile. I tried googling about it i couldn't find a relevant topic. Let me know if there is a solution to run helm .
#12 [8/8] RUN curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3     && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh
#12 0.526 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
#12 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3     && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 22
------
 > [8/8] RUN curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3     && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh:
#12 0.526 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
------
Dockerfile:21
--------------------
  20 |     
  21 | >>> RUN curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 \
  22 | >>>     && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh
  23 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3     && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 22
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Expected result should

```
#11 DONE 7.2s
#12 [8/8] RUN curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3     && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh
#12 0.718 Downloading https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.12.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
#12 1.244 Verifying checksum... Done.
#12 1.683 Preparing to install helm into /usr/local/bin
#12 1.732 helm installed into /usr/local/bin/helm
#12 DONE 2.8s
#13 exporting to image
#13 exporting layers
#13 exporting layers 2.7s done
#13 writing image sha256:fe0634b59e8c9683064ebab0fc2e18c5f164a7b13b71b3ae7aab5310b38aed28 done
#13 naming to docker.io/library/linter:v1.0 0.0s done
#13 DONE 2.7s
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```